# android (arcgis) - keep progress of a seekbar in a window popup after closing it

Tags: android, arcgis, popupwindow, seekbar

I make an application for android. I have an Action in my Action bar, that displays a window popup with a seekbar. This seekbar changes the brightness of the wmsLayer that i have in my mapView. After i close the popup window, the seekbar resets itself. How can i keep the progress after i close the popup?

```
public void showPopup() {

        // Create the Popup Window.
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popup_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.display_window, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
        final PopupWindow popup_win = new PopupWindow(popup_layout, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
        popup_win.showAtLocation(popup_layout, Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
        popup_win.setOutsideTouchable(true);
        popup_win.setFocusable(true);

        Button btnOk = (Button) popup_layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_window);
        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popup_win.dismiss(); 
            }
        });


        // Create the Slider for Brightness.
        slider_brightness = (SeekBar) popup_layout.findViewById(R.id.seekbar_brightness);
        slider_brightness.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progressValue, boolean fromUser) {
                int progress = progressValue;
                wmsLayer.setBrightness(progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Brightness: " + progress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }
```